# Background Color change on a:hover

Tags: css, html, hover, background-color

So I basically want to take a navigation i created with div's and make it so that each line (id) will rollover a different color.

I've tried a ton of different ways of doing it and I'm getting stuck with using the ID correctly I believe.

```
<div class="navcontainer">
        <div id="1"><a href="#">home</a></div>
        <div id="2"><a href="#">work</a></div>
        <div id="3"><a href="#">resume</a></div>
        <div id="4"><a href="#">about</a></div>
        <div id="5"><a href="#">links</a></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.navcontainer {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:24px;
display:block;
}
.navcontainer div a {
background-color:black;
margin:2px;
padding:2px;
display:inline;
float:left;
clear:both;
color:white;
text-decoration:none
}
.navcontainer #1 a:hover {
color:black;
background-color:red;
}
.navcontainer #2 a:hover {
color:black;
background-color:orange;
}
```

Comment: You can't use raw numbers for the IDs. Try `id="link1"` etc.

Comment: Also instead of using DIVs it's generally the more usual practice to use an unordered list as your navigation. <ul><li id="link-1"><a href="#">link 1</a></li></ul>

Comment: @BillyMoat I'm aware of this and had previously formatted using that but do you think using that could affect things later on in dev?

Comment: No, I was just advising best practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never start **ID** & **Class** with `numerical` (1,2,3,) digit. Write like this:

```
#nav1,#nav2...
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="navcontainer">
        <div id="nav1"><a href="#">home</a></div>
        <div id="nav2"><a href="#">work</a></div>
        <div id="nav3"><a href="#">resume</a></div>
        <div id="nav4"><a href="#">about</a></div>
        <div id="nav5"><a href="#">links</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, my brain must not be on tonight.

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Change your ID names to be alpha not starting with a number..

IE:

```
.navcontainer #one a:hover {
color:black;
background-color:red;
}

<div class="navcontainer">
    <div id="one"><a href="#">home</a></div>
    <div id="2"><a href="#">work</a></div>
    <div id="3"><a href="#">resume</a></div>
    <div id="4"><a href="#">about</a></div>
    <div id="5"><a href="#">links</a></div>
</div>
```