# Css how to create navigation bar

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'am trying to make this in css. Trying to make this navigation bar. Any help would be great. 
This is what iam trying to do:

[image]

So the first pic is how it should look like when the user enter the website. Then if they hover over the any of the tabs it should just change color. Any help on trying to make this would be great. I tried this but wont work.

HTML:

```
<div class="horizontal">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Register.html">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="Rules.html">Rules</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Just need to see what the css would look like. Thanks again

EDIT what i have done as people want 2 see:

```
div.horizontal
{
width:809px;
height:63px;
position:relative;
top: -1046px;
left: 104px;
}
div.horizontal ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div.horizontal li
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
div.horizontal a
{
display:block;
width:809px;
}
div.horizontal a:link,div.horizontal a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#000000;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
div.horizontal a:hover,div.horizontal a:active
{
background-color:#999999;
}
```

Like i said this is not right but this is all i can do atm. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  I'm sure there are a billion results for horizontal css menu on Google.

Comment: A similar question has already been asked and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733065/background-color-change-on-ahover

Comment: I have added what i have done. But like i said just trying to make that picture on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your **HTML**, you can do something like this:

**CSS**

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
}

li{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:black;
    border:2px solid gray;
    text-align:center;
}

a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:50px;
    font-style:italic
}

li:hover{
    background:gray;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NuePK/).

Just change the colors.